# How to get a list of all used identifier generators in jpa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am converting an hibernate 4.x application towards spring boot + JPA.
We have lots of integration testing with a number of applications, which requires us to reload the database quite often.

To increase the speed of tests, we developed a flushing capability where we flush all database related information after we reloaded the database (caches, discard queryplans, etc). Part of this functionality is to reset all identifier generators, so they will reinitialize from the database on their next access. We have our own IdGenerator implementation, so we can cast easily and call the correct method to do this (not in the snippet)

In code finding all the identifier generators in Hibernate 4.x looks like this:

```
        Map<String, ClassMetadata> map = hSFactory.getAllClassMetadata();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ClassMetadata> entry : map.entrySet()) {

          EntityPersister entityPersister = hSFactory.getEntityPersister(entry.getKey());
          idGenerators.add(entityPersister.getIdentifierGenerator());
        }
```

However, with later versions of Hibernate the getAllClassMetaData is no longer supported.
So I need to use the `EntityManagerFactory.getMetaModel()` method, but I can not find how to
get the Identifier Generator for each entity.

When debugging and after I obtain the set of `EntityType<?>` with `factory.getMetaModel().getEntities()`, I can see that each EntityType has a reference to the SessionFactoryImpl, which in turn has a list called identifierGenerators, which contains the information I am looking for.

But how to get to that the official way (without hacking with reflection as the inherited sessionFactory() method is protected, so not accessible otherwise).
I'd rather not put reflection based code in as it is likely to break with new versions.